# What's the alternatives to keep my s3 buckets secure in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-s3

Currently, I have an s3 bucket called `stackoverflow2017` with some files:

[image]

**And, the ACL is configured as follow:**

[image]

As you can see the bucket is private and even my own account won't be able to access it.

**I can set a policy to the bucket as follow:**

```
$ aws iam attach-user-policy --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/S3PolicyForDeveloper --user-name developer
```

But, I want to know other alternatives.

**Question:** What are the alternatives and best practices of course for granting access to developers, applications, Etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to keep secure your buckets in s3, I can list these four *Methods for applying permissions*:

- [IAM policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-policies-s3.html)
- [Bucket policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html)
- [Access control lists (ACLs)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html)
- [Query string authentication](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html) / [URL-based access](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html)

The list above follows a **Permission Hierarchy** the first one is the permission with more hierarchy and the last one will be overridden if of one of the previous permissions is present in your security configuration.

***Reference:** [How to secure an Amazon S3 Bucket](https://read.acloud.guru/how-to-secure-an-s3-bucket-7e2dbd34e81b)*

**[IAM policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-policies-s3.html)** are used to grant access to users, groups, or roles — which are applied to other resources. If a user or an AWS resource (e.g., specific set of EC2 instances, Lambda function, another account, etc.) needs to access one or more buckets, this is the way to go. It also helps ensure that you’re applying the principle of least privilege and only granting the permissions necessary.

**[Bucket policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html)** apply to the bucket and the keys within that bucket. If the permissions you need to grant center around the data, bucket policies are the simplest way to accomplish that. This is especially useful for when your bucket is enabled as a static website. You can use a bucket policy to make everything in the bucket read-only.

**[Access control lists](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html)** are hiding underneath the covers for all permissions methods. ACLs are a fine-grained control that allow you to make exceptions to broader tools (like bucket and IAM policies) as needed. In my experience you’ll rarely need to tweak specific ACLs but the ability is there and it makes sense in some application scenarios depending on your bucket/key strategy.

**[Query string authentication](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html)** and **[URL-based access](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html)** are hidden gems in Amazon S3. These methods allow you to grant permissions based on a specific URL. There are two common patterns for using this type of authentication;

- Allowing someone or something to upload a key to your bucket
- Providing temporary access to a specific key

This is a great method of securing providing one-time access to your Amazon S3 buckets.

---

## Alternatives for restricting access to your s3 resources

### 1. Set IAM Policies either to groups or users.

This approach allows you to set an [IAM policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html) to a group or user, you can do that either via CLI, API calls or through the AWS Console.

- **Console**

[image: IAM User]
**IAM User**

Click on link `developer` - press on button `Add permissions`:

[image: IAM Policy]
**IAM Policy**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1515865413837",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:ListObjects"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow", // Can be Denied
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::stackoverflow2017"
    }
  ]
}
```

That Policy `S3PolicyForDeveloper` grants to the user `developer` the permissions for Listing `Buckets` and `Objects` within the bucket `stackoverflow2017`.

For setting policies to groups follow the same steps on Group list.

- **Command Line Interface (CLI)**

**The following command shows how to assign an [IAM policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html) to an IAM user.  Basically, will create a new IAM Policy called `S3PolicyForDeveloper` and immediately will attach it to the IAM user.**

```
$ aws iam put-user-policy --user-name developer --policy-name S3PolicyForDeveloper --policy-document file:///policies/S3PolicyForDeveloper.json
```

[image]

**On the other hand, imagine you want to attach an existing [IAM policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html) to an IAM User, for doing that execute the following command:**

```
$ aws iam attach-user-policy --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/S3PolicyForDeveloper --user-name developer
```

[image]

**The following command shows how to assign an [IAM policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html) to an IAM group.  Basically, will create a new IAM Policy called `S3PolicyForDeveloper` and immediately will attach it to the IAM group.**

```
$ aws iam put-group-policy --group-name developers --policy-document file:///policies/S3PolicyForDeveloper.json --policy-name S3PolicyForDeveloper
```

[image]

**For attaching IAM Policy to groups, execute the following command:**

```
$ aws iam attach-group-policy --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/S3PolicyForDeveloper --group-name developers
```

[image]

### 2. Set Bucket Policies to the Buckets.

A bucket policy allows you to grant specific permissions to specific Buckets.  For example, you could grant access to your bucket either to a specific set of IP addresses, to a specific account in AWS, Etc.

**This is a policy for bucket `stackoverflow2017`:**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1515865416346",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1515865413837",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::stackoverflow2017/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "192.168.1.1"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, the `resource` key contains the [ARN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html) of bucket `stackoverflow2017` plus `/*` to indicate this policy is applied to the bucket's content, the `Condition` key contains the [Policy Conditions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/amazon-s3-policy-keys.html), in this case, this bucket could be read only from IP address `192.168.1.1`.  The `Principal` key contains the user, account, service, or other entity that is allowed or denied access to a resource, in this case to the specified bucket.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1515865416346",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1515865413837",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::stackoverflow2017/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1515865413838",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::stackoverflow2017"
        }
    ]
}
```

The policy above allows to `list/read` and `put` new objects in the bucket `stackoverflow2017` if only if the account doing the operation is `123456789`.

This approach allows you to set a [Bucket policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html) to a bucket, you can do that either via CLI, API calls or through the AWS Console.

- **Console**

Click on bucket `stackoverflow2017` - click on tab Permissions - Click button Bucket Policy.

[image]

Paste the Bucket policy or you can generate it using the [AWS Policy Generator](https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html).

- **Command Line Interface (CLI)**

The command bellow puts a new bucket policy to the bucket `stackoverflow2017` using the file `Stackoverflow2017.json`

```
$ aws s3api put-bucket-policy --bucket stackoverflow2017 --policy file://Stackoverflow2017.json
```

[image]

## Resources

- [AWS Identity and Access Management » API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html)
- [CLI for IAM Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/)
- [IAM Policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html)
- [Bucket Policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html)
- [AWS Policy Generator](https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html)
- [Amazon Resource Names (ARNs) and AWS Service Namespaces](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html)
- [Specifying Conditions in a Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/amazon-s3-policy-keys.html)
- [IAM JSON Policy Elements: Principal](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html)